# Affirm list of events. Where to find

Tags: javascript, documentation, payment, payment-processing

Affirm in the docs shows an example of firing an event:

```
affirm.events.on('learnMore:close',function(){console.log('fired')});
```

where I can find the full list of the events ?

Comment: What is `affirm`? What documentation?

Comment: @Andy https://docs.affirm.com/payments/docs/promo-messaging-getting-started

Comment: I don't think there's one page that has a complete list of events. Just references to [each API's events](https://docs.affirm.com/developers/reference/the-event-object) under their section in the help.